# Passing boost::any to results of boost::bind

Tags: c++, boost

I'm trying to figure out how to write this function:

```
template <typename Bound>
Bound::result_type callFromAnyList(Bound b, list<any> p)
{
}
```

Then, if I had some function:

```
double myFunc(string s, int i)
{
    return -3.0;
}
```

I could call it by doing something like this:

```
list<any> p;
p.push_back((string)"Hello");
p.push_back(7);
double result = callFromAnyList(bind(myFunc, _1, _2), p);
```

Is it possible to write something like my `callFromAnyList` function?  Can you inspect the result type and the parameter types from the type returned from `bind`?  And then call `any_cast<P1>(*p.begin())`, etc?  I've tried to understand the bind code, but it's a little hard to follow, and it doesn't appear as though they wrote it with inspection in mind.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your intent.  You want callFromAnyList to take (1) a function and (2) a list of parameters and then call that function, with that list of parameters, in a type-safe fashion?

Comment: Precisely.  I understand that it's kind of a weird request, but I figure I'll learn a lot about the innards of boost::bind if someone comes up with an answer.

Comment: i think your request is totally valid. i tried what you are going to try some time ago, but failed in figuring out a way. boost::bind has a visitor interface that will call you back with the parameter types and values (if any). but i haven't found a way to just get the parameter types -.-

Comment: To be more clear - I don't really care about boost::bind in this scenario.  What I really care about is inspecting the parameter types of a function.  Is there a different way - boost or not - to do that?  It seems like boost::bind is just the holder, and all the smarts are in bind's operator().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you updated your concerns in the comment sections, here the answer. Just getting the return type of a function is possible:

```
template<typename>
struct return_of;

template<typename R>
struct return_of<R(*)()> {
    typedef R type;
};

template<typename R, typename P1>
struct return_of<R(*)(P1)> {
    typedef R type;
    typedef P1 parameter_1;
};

void foo(int);

template<typename Func>
typename return_of<Func>::parameter_1 bar(Func f) {
    return 42;
}

// call: bar(foo);
```

I guess you see what this comes down to :) You can use boost function types which already has solved it: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/function_types/doc/html/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this for now -

```
void invoke(void (f)(), list<any>& params)
{
    f();
}

template <typename R>
void invoke(R (f)(), list<any>& params)
{
    params.push_front(f());
}

template <typename T0>
void invoke(void (f)(T0), list<any>& params)
{
    T0 t0 = any_cast<T0>(*params.begin()); params.pop_front();
    f(t0);
}

template <typename R, typename T0>
void invoke(R (f)(T0), list<any>& params)
{
    T0 t0 = any_cast<T0>(*params.begin()); params.pop_front();
    params.push_front(f(t0));
}

template <typename T0, typename T1>
void invoke(void (f)(T0, T1), list<any>& params)
{
    T0 t0 = any_cast<T0>(*params.begin()); params.pop_front();
    T1 t1 = any_cast<T1>(*params.begin()); params.pop_front();
    f(t0, t1);
}

template <typename R, typename T0, typename T1>
void invoke(R (f)(T0, T1), list<any>& params)
{
    T0 t0 = any_cast<T0>(*params.begin()); params.pop_front();
    T1 t1 = any_cast<T1>(*params.begin()); params.pop_front();
    params.push_front(f(t0, t1));
}

template <typename T0, typename T1, typename T2>
void invoke(void (f)(T0, T1, T2), list<any>& params)
{
    T0 t0 = any_cast<T0>(*params.begin()); params.pop_front();
    T1 t1 = any_cast<T1>(*params.begin()); params.pop_front();
    T2 t2 = any_cast<T2>(*params.begin()); params.pop_front();
    f(t0, t1, t2);
}

template <typename R, typename T0, typename T1, typename T2>
void invoke(R (f)(T0, T1, T2), list<any>& params)
{
    T0 t0 = any_cast<T0>(*params.begin()); params.pop_front();
    T1 t1 = any_cast<T1>(*params.begin()); params.pop_front();
    T2 t2 = any_cast<T2>(*params.begin()); params.pop_front();
    params.push_front(f(t0, t1, t2));
}
```

I'm lacking the full power of boost::bind - like, I can't handle method pointers - but I also realized that by doing this, I've got a stack processor.  I can keep invoking methods that operator on the parameters on the stack.